# Is String in Java zero index based?

Tags: java

Is String in Java zero index based?

```
String fullName = "Bill Gates";
String a = fullName.substring(0,2);
System.out.println(a);
```

Output:Bi

I tried the above code and the output is "Bi", so according to the output String stores characters with indexes 1,2,3...

Comment: Or does it stores like arrays from 0,1,2,3 ... ?

Comment: please read what this method does: ***String#substring(...)*** [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

Comment: Have you considered that it might just perhaps be a little bit useful to Read the Fine Manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String in java work like arrays. Index begins at 0. I think you are confused with the API, substring(0,2) return 2 characters from the string starting at index 0. Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) should give you an idea of how `stringName.substring()` actually works.